# Disable script loading in head

Tags: header, mootools

How do I disable the loading of

- `mootools-core.js`
- `core.js`

In `<head>` without using a third party component/plugin?

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: @moomoochoo I am using joomla 3.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Im using Joomla 3.2, at the top of my tempate I put:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$dontInclude = array(
'/media/jui/js/jquery.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.js',
'/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js',
'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.js',
'/media/system/js/core-uncompressed.js',
'/media/system/js/tabs-state.js',
'/media/system/js/core.js',
'/media/system/js/mootools-core.js',
'/media/system/js/mootools-core-uncompressed.js',
);

foreach($doc->_scripts as $key => $script){
    if(in_array($key, $dontInclude)){
        unset($doc->_scripts[$key]);
    }
}
```

This prevents those scripts from being included, add or remove scripts as needed

Comment: This failed on my last project (joomla 3.3.6). I added `JURI::root(true).` before the script paths and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can unset it in the template

```
unset(
  $this->_scripts['/media/jui/js/mootools-core.js'],
  $this->_scripts['/media/jui/js/core.js']);
```

This will remove the both JS files from the Header.

Answer (score 4):

In Joomla 3.x, you can call `JHtml::_('jquery.framework')` in your template to load jQuery without Mootools. This loads jQuery in no conflict mode by default so if you need normal mode, just add a second parameter of **false**: `JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false)`.

[http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Javascript_Frameworks](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aJavascript_Frameworks)

Answer (score 2):

I've used this:

```
foreach ($doc->_scripts as $script => $value)
{
    if (preg_match('/media\/jui/i', $script))
      unset($doc->_scripts[$script]);
}
```

Comment: Since your `needle` string is not variable and the only intention is to make a case-insensitive match, then it would be better practice to use [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) ... `if (stripos($script, 'media/jui') !== false)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @ContextSwitch wasnt working for me due to some scripts were being loaded after the template was processed so unsetting the files at that stage had no effect on those files.

So I had to implement the similar solution but using a simple plugin bound to `onBeforeCompileHead` event. As described by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796527/807104).